# How to make links send DELETE requests?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, hyperlink, http-delete

I have this link in my view. It clears the cart (I'm developing an online store):

```cs
@Html.ActionLink("Clear", "Clear")
```

It works fine, but doesn't fit the HTTP specification. It sends a `GET` request that changes the current state (clears cart), and it is said in the specification that `GET` requests shouldn't be "changing".

There is a similar question on Stack Overflow that has an accepted answer. It suggests using `Ajax.ActionLink` and specifying `HttpMethod = "POST"` in the `AjaxOptions`. However, it doesn't fit because of these reasons:

- I want my link to send `DELETE` requests (because there is already a handler for `POST` for deleting specific items. It receives a form.)
- I don't want to use Ajax links (if possible).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you can have a form and do a http post with it

Comment: @EhsanSajjad But how do I send a DELETE request?